# Download & install Report Lab on CentOs

Tags: centos, yum

I am following [this link](http://www.paulodev.com.br/en/blog/linux/37-download-google-book-in-linux) to install `report lab` and download parts of googlebooks as pdf.

However, I am on CentOs 5, can not use `apt-get`, probably I need to use `yum`, but I do not know how.

Any suggestion please?

EDIT: I have tried `yum install ...` but many packages are not available.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Download ZIP http://www.reportlab.com/ftp/pfbfer.zip

```
wget http://www.reportlab.com/ftp/pfbfer.zip
```

2.- Create folder named "fonts" in " /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/"

```
sudo mkdir fonts
```

3.- Copy content of folder extracted in "fonts" folder

```
sudo yum install unzip    
sudo unzip ../pfbfer.zip
```

4.- Restart server

```
reboot
```